# Query pages created by deleted users

Tags: wp-query, users, query

I need to query all and any pages that are created by either deleted users or users that are no longer users of the website.

Here is my query

```
$args = array(
'author'  => '0',
'post_type' => 'page',
'orderby' => 'modified',
'order'   => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

I tried to change 'author' to something like '-1' or 'userdoesntexist' and none of these seem to work. I get a list of all pages on the website instead.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress gives you a few options on the Dashboard when you delete a user. As far as I am aware the options are:

1. Delete the user but keep their name / credit on created content
2. Delete the user and attribute their content to another user
3. Delete the user AND delete their content

Unless there were changes to this functionality, you will need to alter the query to find either the author that was deleted or alter it to find the pages authored by the user who took over that content when the original user was deleted.